# Efficient Rolling Window Identification in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have time-series data with some missing data for which I am running some estimation function over rolling windows. The windows are not uniform length and each variable has differing start and end dates. I want to remove any windows which have any missing data. The windows overlap, so a single missing observation will often remove a great many windows from consideration. What I want is a mapping from each date into the windows which contain it.

Currently, I have a logical matrix which has a row for every possible day and then each column represents one of the windows with true values for the days of that window. I can then subset that matrix to rows representing the missing data, and whichever columns contain any true values are the invalid windows. The problem is that the logical matrix gets large (10k x 10k ~100mb) and there can be many. I can convert to sparse which solves the size problem, but the calculation of which windows to remove becomes very slow when the windows are long.

This doesn't smell like a problem that should be resource intensive (either memory or computation), is there a better way?

Edit: Let me add an example so this may be a little clearer. Say the full set of dates range from 1 to 100. Windows are 1:10, 2:11, 3:12 and so on through to 91:100 (these are uniform, but it doesn't matter for the example). I have a series that runs from 5 to 25, but has NaN for 17.

That one NaN knocks out ten windows (8:17 through to 17:26). I want an efficient mapping from observation 17 to windows 8:17. Clearly, it's pretty easy when the windows are uniform length, but what is an efficient method when the windows are irregular?

Comment: I don't understand.  What is wrong (or insufficient) with `(date >= begin(i) && data < end(i))`?  You need to give an example of how your intend to use this information.

Comment: @Oli I've added an example that I hope makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded up Jonas' solution and it ended up being slower than what I already had in place. It did remove the need for the large array, however, and it got me thinking about the problem differently. I just needed to go from a window -> (obs start, obs end) mapping to an obs -> (indices of each window that obs falls into) approach.

So I build a cell-array that contains each set of window indices for each day (I could use a NumObsx2 matrix, but I want to allow for possibly complicated window definition). For each timeseries, I use the indices of each missing data point to subset the mapping to get the indices of all the windows that need to be removed. Then cell2mat pulls the indices out of the cell-array and I can remove the bad windows (Matlab doesn't care about repeated indices in assignments, thankfully).

In my timings, this method is about 10x my original method and 15x than Jonas' method. The indices in the map can be stored as uint16, so the memory required is far less than my orignal solution (but still more than Jonas' method).

As a bonus, I can use accumarray to count up the indices if I want to use more complicated criteria such as no more than 5 NaNs (cf no more than one as described).

Comment: Interesting. By the way, if you were store the indices in a n-by-1 cell array `idxCell`, would calling `badWindows = cellfun(@(x)any(isnan(data(x))),idxCell)` be fast, or would you again do too much testing?

Comment: I think it's too much testing - each cell of idxCell would contain all the indices to the data for that window, so you would be checking isnan for each observation within each window (rather than just per observation).On the other hand, the vectorized code is much prettier...

Answer (score 3):

Logical comparisons cost little time and resources. Are you really sure that this is a bottleneck?

If the window creation is time-consuming, you may want do it in a `while`-loop, so that you can skip a few entries if you encounter a `NaN` inside a window.

If window creation is fast, which it would certainly be with uniform lengths, you can simply do

```
%# startEnd is created according to your example, but can be whatever quick method
startEnd = [(1:(100-windowSize+1))',(windowSize+1:100)'];
nanIdx = find(isnan(data))';  %'#

%# This line temporarily creates a logical array of size nWindows-by-numberOfNaNs
%# which is most likely smaller than nWindows-by-nWindows
badWindows = any(bsxfun(@le,startEnd(:,1),nanIdx) & bsxfun(@ge,startEnd(:,2),nanIdx),2);

startEnd(badWindows,:) = [];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had thought of this approach - the problem is that we end up doing doing enormous numbers of redundant isnan checks (every observation for every window it is within, rather than just once per observation). If each window is around a hundred observations, we'll be checking (almost) 100 times per observation. I want to check the time series once and then map this into the windows.

Comment: It was the bottleneck and I was surprised at that as well. However, I think the issue was that I was subsetting the complete matrix down to the rows that I had data for (5:25 in the example). I really like your solution, it's an elegant use of bsxfun and should be extremely efficient in the common case of no missing data.

Comment: I coded this up and, somewhat surpisingly, it turned out to be slower, I think due to still checking each missing data point against all possible windows (rather than indexing in as in the method I describe). I worked out what I think is a better method which is described below.